Compilation failed when using gfortran flag default-real-8 and stdlib
I am trying to compile my program in 64 bits. I use gfortran and the option default-real-8 to compile :
-fdefault-real-8    Set the default real type to an 8 byte wide type. 
I use the stdlib of Fortran
but got an error:
build\dependencies\stdlib\src\stdlib_specialfunctions_gamma.f90:1175:18:

 1175 |             res = l_gamma(n + 1, 1.0D0)
      |                  1
Error: There is no specific function for the generic 'l_gamma' at (1)

If I believe the error, the function containing this call is
impure elemental function l_factorial_iint64(n) result(res)
    integer(int64), intent(in) :: n

    [...]
    
    res = l_gamma(n + 1, 1.0D0)
end function

So n being int(8) and 1.0D0 being real(8), I think it should find this overload:
impure elemental function l_gamma_iint64dp(z, x) result(res)
    integer(int64), intent(in) :: z
    real(dp), intent(in) :: x

    [...]

end function

But apparently not. Pretty new to Fortran and the kind stuff, I guess I am missing something!

Can you explain why you need to use -fdefault-real-8? Unless you have a very good reason, the best answer you can get to solving problems with -fdefault-real-8 is to not use -fdefault-real-8.

But anyway: where are the default reals in the code? (Don't forget that 1.0d0 is also made 16-byte.)

I know I should not use default-real-8, but I think this is still a bug in the stdlib, 1.0D0 is not used anywhere in the code, it should just use the default real, especially because res is defined as a default real.

I can not upvote @francescalus enough - Do not use any flag that changes the kind of default types, you are just asking for a life of pain. Write the code properly in the first place.

"So I guess default-real-8 is promoting 1.0D0 from REAL(8) to REAL(16)". You needn't guess: that's explicitly said in the manual for that option.

I have a huge application, and I need to test stuff, and initially it will take less work to test first with this flag to see if it is worth the time to rewrite the whole thing with good handling of fortran's kind. And the interesting part I think is that there may be a bug in the stdlib.

I fully agree with the other commenters: using compiler options that change the kinds is something to avoid as far as possible. That said, to be fully consistent and portable, stdlib should not use 1.0d0 as an actual argument for a dummy argument that is real(dp): it should use 1.0_dp instead. You may report this issue on the github repo of stdlib.

Yes that's exactly that @PierU, thank you, here is the PR https://github.com/fortran-lang/stdlib/pull/876

One of the reasons to not use these options is that they often turn the compiler into a non standard conforming mode. For instance, promoting the default real to real(8) normally requires also promoting the default integer to the integer(8) and the default logical to logical(8). Otherwise some standard-conforming codes may be broken.

Try the -freal-4-real-8 option.  Read the documentation that came with your compiler.  It likely does what you want.  The individual that gave gfortran the -fdefault-real-8 option tried to maintain storage association, but he managed to do a poor job.

The assumption that

1.0D0 being real(8)

is false. 1.0D0 WILL be promoted from a REAL(8) to REAL(16) under default-real-8, the documentation is very clear:

This option promotes the default width of DOUBLE PRECISION and double real constants like 1.d0 to 16 bytes if possible.

Since the l_gamma has no overload on real(16), the compilation fails.
